# UIElement does not change property on first Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I guess this is a very basic question, but why does WPF not change a property (e.g. Background) on second but not on first click? I use a ViewModel to store the values from my UI. So I can easily access them when the user clicks the Save button.

The ViewModel contains several properties, here is just an excerpt:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Drawing = System.Drawing;
using Media = System.Windows.Media;

using BarcodeLib;

namespace BarcodeEncoder
{
    class BarcodeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // Some more properties

        private Media.Brush foreColor;
        public Media.Brush ForeColor
        {
            get { return this.foreColor; }
            set
            {
                if (this.foreColor != value)
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("ForeColor");

                this.foreColor = value;
            }
        }

        private Media.Brush backColor;
        public Media.Brush BackColor
        {
            get { return this.backColor; }
            set
            {
                if (this.backColor != value)
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("BackColor");

                this.backColor = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

        public BarcodeViewModel()
        {
            // Initialisation of the other properties
            this.ForeColor = new Media.SolidColorBrush(Media.Colors.Black);
            this.BackColor = new Media.SolidColorBrush(Media.Colors.White);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the relevan XAML markup:

```
 <StackPanel
    x:Name="rootElement"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:BarcodeViewModel />
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <!-- Some more UI elements -->
    <StackPanel
            x:Name="pForeColor"
            Background="{Binding ForeColor}"
            Width="Auto" Height="23"
            Margin="5,0,5,0"
            MouseDown="pForeColor_MouseDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And last but not least the MouseDown Event handler:

```
private void pForeColor_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    using (var cd = new Forms.ColorDialog())
    {
        if (cd.ShowDialog() == Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            this.bcvm.ForeColor = new Media.SolidColorBrush()
            {
                Color = Media.Color.FromArgb(cd.Color.A, cd.Color.R, cd.Color.G, cd.Color.B)
            };
    }
}
```

So if I try to set the color of the StackPanel `pForeColor`, the ColorDialog opens but when clicking OK the panel does not change color. Only when doing this again and submitting the selection, the previous selected color appears.

So can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Please don't force tags into the title. The tags section ensures they will be index correctly and recognized by other users

Answer (score 0):

Ok...got it!

The mistake is, that the `OnPropertyChanged` Methode is called (and this way also the `PropertyChanged` Event) BEFORE setting the new Color.

Just check, if a new value is set, then set the new value and then raise the event